# Match both domain.com/app and domain.com/app/ when using root: '/app/' and pushState: true

Tags: backbone.js

When starting my application I have

```
Backbone.history.start
  pushState: true
  root: '/app'
```

and in my routes I have

```
routes:
  ''      : 'index'  # matches /app/ but not /app
  'stores': 'stores' # matches /app/stores/ and /app/stores
```

which matches mydomain.com/app/ but not mydomain.com/app.
The extra / looks ugly and all the other routes match both with and without the /.
How can I have the root also match without the trailing /?

Comment: I have the same issue, I hope there is an answer to this.